# Ffmpeg PNG image sequence into 360 video

Tags: ffmpeg, type-conversion, png, blender, 360-panorama

I'm trying to make a PNG sequence I got from blender(already in equirectangular format, same properties all files) into 360 equirectangular video for projection mapping. My files have 2 step frame rate resulting in file names such as 002-004-006.... How is this done with ffmpeg? I'm total noob with this program :) Thank you.

I checked ffmpeg website, however for 360 format with filenames that does not have one step like 01-02-03, instead 2 steps like 02-04-06, I did not really understand how to convert my 7000 PNG images into 360 video.

Comment: I think you can pass a filename to `ffmpeg` with `-i filelist.txt` Then, inside `filelist.txt` you put `file XXX-02.png` then on next line `file XXX-04.png`

Comment: Thanks! And to keep the 360 feature, is there a code?

Comment: I don't know what the 360 feature is.

Comment: Sorry, let me put it like this: For the output video file of ffmpeg of these images (PNG's) to be a 360 video can I use this line? "-vf  v360=equirect" ?

Comment: I don't see why not. Try it - you have the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not answer your question quite right, but there is a small Python program from Google on GitHub, the "[Spatial Media Metadata Injector](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/tree/master/spatialmedia)", which simply sets some metadata so that your (equirectangular) rendered video is played in the media player or on YouTube as a 360° video.

With this ffmpeg command you can convert your PNG image sequence into a video beforehand:

`ffmpeg -start_number 2 -i %03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4`

Unfortunately, I don't know how to select only every second number as the file name.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. İn the comment above it is explained how to import a list of selected files : -i filelist.txt (put all the image file paths in this .txt file) However, about your code I have a question: libx264 this is for h.264 video codec I guess, -r for frame rate and -pix_fmt yuv.. for color pixel space. So indeed if I have sRGB color space this is where I change in the code? I also saw in another post someone used -vf v360=equirect to convert another video format to 360. Do you know this method? Thanks!